# How to disable user specific tmpfs /run/user/1000, tmpfs

Tags: systemd, pam, tmpfs

Is there any way to disable system creating user specific tmp mount `/run/user/1000`, tmpfs per each log-in session?

I know this is a new feature, but I want to get the system running older way.

Comment: Yep, I agree this XDG_RUNTIME_DIR is an annoy feature.  Glad that you have found a way to disable it.

Answer (score 4):

This directory appears to be created by `pam_sytemd`. If you are comfortable losing the functionality described in `man pam_systemd`, then you can edit `/etc/pam.d/systemd-user` and comment out this line:

```
session optional pam_systemd.so
```

Then reboot (or just try logging into a new session). I have not tested what side-effects this change might have, so beware!

The `pam_systemd.so` entry may be in another file, depending on your distribution and any local changes; others have reported that they had to edit `/etc/pam.d/password-auth-ac`, `/etc/pam.d/common-session`, or `/etc/pam.d/runuser-l`.

Comment: Thanks Mark.Tested this, but doesn't work. My OS is RHEL 7.2.